# R using ignoring NA's when using unique

Tags: r, unique, na

I am attempting to find/discard rows based on their similarity in column values and have the following example code:

```
vec1 <- c("B","D","E","NA")    
vec2 <- c("B","D","E","NA")    
vec3 <- c("B","C","E","NA")    
vec4 <- c("B","D","E","NA")    
vec5 <- c("B","NA","E","E")    
vec6 <- c("B","NA","NA","NA")

mat1 <- cbind(vec1,vec2,vec3,vec4,vec5,vec6)
mat1
     vec1 vec2 vec3 vec4 vec5 vec6
[1,] "B"  "B"  "B"  "B"  "B"  "B" 
[2,] "D"  "D"  "C"  "D"  "NA" "NA"
[3,] "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "NA"
[4,] "NA" "NA" "NA" "NA" "E"  "NA"

rows = apply(mat1, 1, function(i) length(unique(i)) > 1 )
mat2 <- mat1[rows, ]
     vec1 vec2 vec3 vec4 vec5 vec6
[1,] "D"  "D"  "C"  "D"  "NA" "NA"
[2,] "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "NA
[3,] "NA" "NA" "NA" "NA" "E"  "NA"
```

How may I change the code above to achieve this? In the help file for `unique` it suggests there is an `incomparables` argument, is this implemented and can it be used? I don't necessarily wish to remove the `NA`'s just ignore them.

Comment: `rows = apply(mat1, 1, function(i) length(unique(i[!(i=="NA")]))>1)`

Comment: So do you have a character with the value "NA" or do you have a proper R NA value? `vec1 <- c("B","D","E","NA")` is very different than `vec1 <- c("B","D","E",NA)`

Comment: I have a character with the value NA.

Comment: @Vlo Your comment worked perfectly thank you. Could you add it as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From comment above

`rows = apply(mat1, 1, function(i) length(unique(i[!(i=="NA")]))>1)`

Comment: Yeah, if you want to do it the bad way, sure. What happens when one of the IDs is AN?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need them to be properly entered for `is.na` to work as it should. Currently they are character strings, and `NA` has is classed to we can assign `NA_character_` to be safe.
 Also, I would recommend a `summary`  Here are a few table that get the information you need.

`length(unique(...))` is essentially a `table`

```
> mat1[is.na(mat1)]  
# character(0)  ## not good 
> mat1[mat1 == "NA"] <- NA_character_
> mat1[is.na(mat1)]  ## notice the difference...
# [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA

 > summary(mat1)
   vec1     vec2     vec3     vec4     vec5     vec6  
 B   :1   B   :1   B   :1   B   :1   B   :1   B   :1  
 D   :1   D   :1   C   :1   D   :1   E   :2   NA's:3  
 E   :1   E   :1   E   :1   E   :1   NA's:1           
 NA's:1   NA's:1   NA's:1   NA's:1       

> apply(mat1, 2, function(x) length(table(x)))
vec1 vec2 vec3 vec4 vec5 vec6 
   3    3    3    3    2    1 

> as.table(t(mat1))
     A B C D
vec1 B D E  
vec2 B D E  
vec3 B C E  
vec4 B D E  
vec5 B   E E
vec6 B
```